# Laravel 5 + memcached setup

Tags: laravel, memcached

I'm really just looking for an explanation about memecached and laravel. I understand what it does, but can I use my memcached installation with laravel. More specifically:

```
    'memcached' => [
        'driver' => 'memcached',
        'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
        'sasl' => [
            env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
            env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
        ],
        'options' => [
            // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
        ],
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                'weight' => 100,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I know/will set up the server aspect, and I get what the options do...but persistent_id, a memcached um and pw...what are they? Their uses? etc.. typically laravel is extremely well document but on memcached it says very little (And the little it does, seems to be dated and not based on 5.0 laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is explanation from php.net:

> By default the Memcached instances are destroyed at the end of the request. To create an instance that persists between requests, use **persistent_id** to specify a unique ID for the instance. All instances created with the same **persistent_id** will share the same connection.

http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.construct.php

So for your project just define a unique name for it.
Hope it helps.